# downloadHandler saying file not found although the file exists in tempdir

Tags: r, shiny

I'm unable to get downloadHandler to work properly. Have tried running it in all types of web browsers with the same result.

Example code:

```
library(shiny)
library(datasets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Test"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(),
    mainPanel(
      downloadButton("download_csv", "Download"),
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  data <- mtcars
  output$download_csv <- downloadHandler (
    filename = "data.csv",
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(data, file)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I keep getting the error message "File does not exist: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpwhlAv0\file6734375447bf.csv" and the web browser reports that the download has failed. But when I go to the temporary directory, I see that the temporary file exists and has the data I want.

What's going on? Is access to the file somehow denied for the web browsers?

Comment: Your UI code is is flawed (Please see my edit). The server part is working fine.

Comment: @ismirsehregal You mean the app runs fine on your computer? Do you get a csv file to download with mtcars data?

Comment: exactly, tested with chrome.